# Endless session using securesocial

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, securesocial

i'm using Play 2.2 and SecureSocial 2.1.3 I already have all the login/sign up workflow working but i don't know how to keep the users logged *forever* and with a non-expiring session. I read the [documentation](http://securesocial.ws/guide/configuration.html) and it doesn't say nothing about this but maybe i missed something.

Here is my securesocial.conf (i'm setting makeTrasient to true to keep the cookie after the browser is closed)

```
cookie {
        #name=coalition
        #path=/
        #domain=some_domain
        httpOnly=true
        idleTimeoutInMinutes=30
        absoluteTimeoutInMinutes=720
        makeTransient=false

}
```

I also have my echached customized for avoid the login after reloading the application

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../config/ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false">
<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
<defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
        diskPersistent="true"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
/>
```

The users in this type of web application would benefit more by loggin in once than re-loging every time they visit the site or every *XXXX* minutes when the session expires.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about putting absoluteTimeout to a big big value ?

Comment: I thought about that but i wanted to know if there was a answer for an endless session.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will answer your question.
https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/issues/377

Comment: This doesn't answer my question i have Ehached configurated but as far as i know that is for keep users loged after reload/redeploy the application. I want the session to live forever.

Comment: Ok, so I think you'll need a JavaScript that from times to times "ping" in a service. That will makes the session to live until the browser is closed.

Comment: Remember that the service that the JS pings need to require the authentication annotations.